# Crop an image by making a gesture Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-gesture

I want to crop an image when you make a 'Square' gesture on that image. It should take the nearest possible square or rectangle and crop the region inside the drawn gesture.

1. Is it possible to get the co-ordinates of the drawn square with respect to the image?
2. Which is the best API or plugin for cropping?.

I have developed application involving gestures and images so I have basic knowledge.